# Числительные

Tags: числительные, орфография

как правильно сократить числительное?и почему?Например такое предложение:Опрос проводился в 22-ух городах/22-х городах?

Answer (score 1):

Вообще-то, я бы не советовала вообще их как-то сокращать. Просто: "В 22 городах". Но если хочется уточнить падеж, то все-таки "В 22-х". Ну, или третий вариант - написать словами: "В двадцати двух городах" - тогда уж никто не придерется))))

Answer (score 1):

"В 22-х" -- это в двадцать вторых городах. [К количественным числительным окончания не наращивают.](http://ru.wikibooks.org/wiki/%D0%A0%D1%83%D1%81%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B9_%D1%8F%D0%B7%D1%8B%D0%BA/%D0%9D%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%89%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5_%D0%BE%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BD%D1%87%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B9_%D0%BA_%D1%87%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%BC_%D0%B2_%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%84%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B9_%D1%84%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BC%D0%B5)